# how to make fast query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

i tested this coding SQL on create small table it have 4 row data and i get fast query but when i change to true table deep time and don't give me any result, this truth table it have more than 1 million record

```
SELECT DISTINCT /*+ richs_secret_hint */
 em_code, (to_date(end_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') - level + 1) AS days
FROM
   islaam_vca where em_code = '2222'

CONNECT BY level <= (to_date(end_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date(start_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') + 1)
order by days ASC
;
```

give me fast result

any one help me how can get fast result from true table

Comment: What does the explain output say? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231

Comment: Do you have an index on `islaam_vca(em_code)`? How many rows in your table match `islaam_vca where em_code = '2222'`?

Comment: On a side note: Do you really store the dates as strings, so you must convert them with `TO_DATE`? Don't do this, use the appropriate data type `DATE` to store dates. Then, is `em_code` numeric or not? You compare it with a string, but that string contains a number.

Comment: I for one would like to know what `richs_secret_hint` is supposed to do. Alas it's not the magical "go faster" hint everybody seems to be looking for. So what is it?

Comment: Do you have an index on islaam_vca(em_code)? How many rows in your table match islaam_vca where em_code = '2222'?  2 ROW START DATE  TO END DATE

Comment: These are two questions. You only answered the second one. And I don't even understand the answer. You say that you have two rows for one `em_code`, but then you mention "start date to end date". Every row has a start and end date. So you have two rows, i.e. two different date ranges for this sample em_code? Is this the typical number of rows per em_code or can it be many more? And please answer whether an index on islaam_vca(em_code) exists.

Comment: i will explain what i want . i have table vacation for Emp have more data 1903020 count row  contains column empcode , startdat , enddate ok . exm 12-02-2015 to 20-02-2015 , and this query make Convert each date range into each day row 12-02-2015....13-02-2015 ...... when i test on true table it's take more more time create another table same true table and insert 4 row of data and test query give me fast result knowing true table i create index for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To me it seems that combination of em_code and start_date is a unique for this table, so there should exists index for this uniqueness:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX islaam_vca_uk1 ON islaam_vca(em_code, start_date)
```

2. Second, please store dates as DATE datatype, not as string.
3. Tested it a bit and there could be situation, when query will try TABLE ACCESS FULL for table islaam_vca, so you could try to do:

```
SELECT /*+ALL_ROWS*/  distinct em_code --sorry about my interpretation of secret your hint
     , start_date
     , NVL(end_date, SYSDATE) end_date --don't know if end date is nullable or now
     , TRUNC(start_date) + level - 1 specific_date
  FROM (SELECT em_code
            , start_date
            , end_date
         FROM islaam_vca
        WHERE em_code = '2222')
CONNECT BY level <= TRUNC(NVL(end_date, SYSDATE)) - TRUNC(start_date) + 1
order by specific_date;
```

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Comment: i need to get all employ can you help me [artbro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610387/artbro)